# Test to see if URL exists

Tags: python, curl

What is the best way to test if a URL exists in python, I currently use cURL however I wanted to switch to use python

In cURL I use something like

```
curl http://www.google.com | tidy -i
```

together with a bash script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way is probably something like

```
import httplib

try:
    url = httplib.HTTPConnection('yahoo.com')
    url.connect()
except httplib.HTTPException as ex:
    print "not connected"
```